# AWS Grafana sees identical data for all custom metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have created some custom metric filters for a cloudtrail log group, 11 in total.

Each  metric filter is filtering for multiple related events (one is for iam changes, another is for user logon activity, etc).

I want to log each time one of these metric filters captures an event and show it on an AWS Grafana dashboard.

I have the CDK to deploy the metric filters, they show up in cloudwatch and I can see them graphing events in the AWS Console.

I can even add the datasource and correct permissions to access it from AWS Grafana.

It's only when I go to render the results onto the dashboard panel that I start to see a problem. All of he metrics have the same data.

I have tried to add all metrics and they all show the same data. I have included some screenshots to demonstrate the issue.

[image]

[image]